# Two grouping variables in a dotplot

Tags: r, plot, grouping, lattice

I am trying to create a simple `dotplot` (`lattice` package) in R with the following data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(Sediment=c("Algae", "Algae", "Algae", "Bare", "Bare", "Bare", "Dredged", "Dredged", "Dredged"), Rep=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), LeafElongation=c(0, 20.6, 0, 29.1, 41.4, 45.9, 54.1, 22.3, 26.7))
```

I would like to use marker colors to group the data by Sediment and marker shapes to group data by Rep. This is my code so far:

```
dotplot(LeafElongation~Sediment, data=df, groups=Sediment, method="jitter", col = 
      c("darkolivegreen", "darkgoldenrod3", "sienna"), main= "Leaf Elongation: Ramet Plots", ylab="Average total plant leaf elongation (cm)", cex.main=1.7, cex.lab=1.2, cex.axis=1.7)
```

I have successfully grouped my data by sediment and this is generally how I would like the plot to appear, but I would like to have a different shape for each Rep (circles for 1, diamonds for 2, triangles for 3). I would also like the shapes to be filled rather than open.  Additionally, I believe the `jitter` method is supposed to separate overlapping points so that both can be seen, but it does not appear to be working in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pch` argument is what you are looking for. Just add it to your code and feed it directly with `df$Rep`. You can remove the argument `groups`, that now unnecessary.

```
dotplot(LeafElongation~Sediment, data=df, 
    method="jitter", 
    col = c("darkolivegreen", "darkgoldenrod3", "sienna"), 
    main= "Leaf Elongation: Ramet Plots", 
    ylab="Average total plant leaf elongation (cm)", 
    cex.main=1.7, cex.lab=1.2, cex.axis=1.7,
    pch = df$Rep)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this as an additional argument to your dotplot to group by shape.
     `pch = c(16, 17, 18)[df$Rep]`

You can swap out 16, 17, 18 for any other shapes as per this guide: http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/pchsymbols.php

Comment: I added this argument right before the color argument and it has filled in my dots, but still did not alter their shape. Do I also need to add "Rep" to the beginning of the code somewhere?

Comment: Never mind I solved the problem.  Need to remove the "groups" argument and create a color argument for Sediment in the same way you suggested.